# Call method in separate application in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I am trying to set up a couple of application in Objective-C/Xcode, one background application ("Application is agent"), and a preference pane.

I am having trouble communicating between both of these applications.  I believe this is possible using NSNotification, but I am wondering if this is possible using delegation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, `NSNotificationCenter` can be used only in ONE app. and [NSDistributedNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDistributedNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) can be used to accomplish your objective.